# Convert PSD to SVG and add white path to a colored image

Tags: svg, css

I have a coloured logo that I have created in photoshop.  I would like to export this to SVG, however, I also need to add a white path to it so that I can use CSS to display it in white on some background.  I have no idea how to do this as I am only a basic user with PS6

I would greatly appreciate your help and advice - I have been trying to sort this out for weeks readying articles and frankly, it is doing my head in.

Cheers,
Darren

Comment: Create your logo using vector image editing software instead, such as: Adobe Illustrator, or free software such as Inkscape(dot)org.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of svg is to be vector based while photoshop is pixel based. The advantage of svg is its scaleability without loss of information while a pixel based image will become blurry when scaling it up. 
You have to rebuild it vector based with e.g. illustrator. if its a simple shape this shouldnt be a hard task. But a simple conversion is not possible

Comment: Thank you, Pat, I have got a guy working on the Vector-based version now.